# Adding a column to polygon table with correct corresponding address

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, spatial-join, address

I have 2 shapefiles:

- one with polygons (buildings) and their properties
- other one is a point address shapefile - it contains points that are inside polygons from the other SHP, but it's still another layer.

I need to add 3 columns to Polygons layer from Address layer. How to do it so the records will match correctly?

So far I got to know I can use ST_Intersect in SQL, but I'm not sure it's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) - This will allow you to join the two layers spatially, but each join will output a summary, not individual records.

What you need is a [related table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/joins-and-relates.htm). You can create a 1-many relate from the polygon to the records within.

Create a relationship class and define the relationship using a spatial intersect.

Comment: A building can have one address only and the opposite. Would it be 1:1 rather than 1:n? I exclude possibility of 2 buildings with same address because I know my db is constructed this way. But if I did, would it actually work if some buildings don't have an address point over them? Just as a house and a garage next to it.

Comment: Please edit your original question to be more specific on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something about types of relation. I'll try to do what you suggested when I'll have access to data.

Comment: I used spatial join module in QGis named "Join attributes by location" and it worked perfectly. Thank you!